# Ethernet limited to 10Mbps after reinstalling motherboard

Tags: networking, ethernet

I know there are plenty of threads on this topic already, but I can't get it to work.

Whenever I try to set it to Auto Negotiation, I get the error of an unidentified network. When I set it to 10Mbps Full Duplex it works perfectly.

What I have done:

- Flushed DNS
- Bought a new Cat6 cable as well as trying with 5 older cables.
- Tried all 5 ports on the router.
- Resetting Network settings.
- Uninstalling Network Card (and driver)

Am I right in assuming I somehow damaged the Ethernet port or the network card during the reinstall?

Comment: What if you try with some Live Linux distro or may be some third-party Windows live disk as live USB boot and check again? Also make sure that all power cables are firmly inserted in the respective sockets on the motherboard.

Comment: @patkim I had installed a brand new Windows created with the Media Creation Tool on an almost brand new USB stick, so i dont really believe there should be an issue with that right? As for Linux i will try that as i will need it anyway.

Comment: Another thing you can try is to run the system outside of the cabinet and recheck port speed. This will hopefully try to eliminate anything like static charges or even some short somewhere.

Comment: What happens if you set it to _100_ Mbps full-duplex? If it works at 10 and 100 Mbps but not at 1 Gbps, then it might be that one of the "other" 2 pairs is damaged.

Comment: @patkim i will try that, especially since the io shield had some issues right out of the box and never really fit. Might actually be an issue

Comment: @user1686 If i set it to anything higher than 10Mbps it will just say unidentified network and not work at all.

Comment: Hmm oh right, if one side is manual (no auto negotiation), the other side will always assume 10 Mbps unless you set *both* sides manually... Do you have another computer to test against directly?

Comment: I installed a network card and it perfectly works at 100Mbps now, no idea why the ethernet port was limited to 10 all of the sudden though